# Pass FedAuth cookies from WebApi controller to RestSharp

Tags: cookies, asp.net-web-api, single-sign-on, restsharp, ws-federation

We have a thinktecture powered identity server used for SSO. There are several services which utilize that identity server. My app uses ASP.net WebApi controllers to handle UI requests. For a particular request I have to make a REST API call to one of the mentioned above services. That service requires authentication of course. What I'm trying to do is to pass FedAuth cookies from the current request to RestSharp client:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/testroute")]
    public IHttpActionResult Test()
    {
        var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(_someBaseUrl);
        var req = new RestSharp.RestRequest(_someUrl);
        var cookies = Request
            .Headers
            .GetCookies()
            .SelectMany(x => x.Cookies)
            .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("FedAuth"))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var cookie in cookies)
        {
            req.AddCookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
        }

        var resp = client.Execute(req);
        return Ok(resp);
    }
```

RestSharp client call fails with 500 error code with the following stacktrace inside:

```
[FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.]
System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength) +14390795
System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength) +162
System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +56
System.IdentityModel.Services.ChunkedCookieHandler.ReadInternal(String name, HttpCookieCollection requestCookies) +424
System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(SessionSecurityToken&amp; sessionToken) +99
System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +173
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +165
```

Is my approach for user authorization correct? If so, am I doing something wrong with the cookies (from the stacktrace it looks like they are being corrupted)?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `FedAuth` cookie was encoded. Maybe you can check if your FedAuth cookie contains char like `'%'`. If yes, just decode `FedAuth` before you use it.